# how is possible to set imageview or icon in the canvas circle?

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, icons

how is possible to set an image or icon in the canvas Circle? i have a custom canvas view that by move the camera on map, resize method will be activate and change the shape of the view and by stop the moving of map it will be like factory setting...happy english :-))))

```
public class CancvasCircle extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView {
  ///main circle  resize fields
  public static final int MAIN_CIRCLE_PRE_RADIUS = 40;
  public static final int MAIN_CIRCLE_POST_RADIUS = 43;
  public static final String MAIN_CIRCLE_PRE_STROKE_COLOR = "#69DAE2";
  //4CEAE3
  public static final String MAIN_CIRCLE_POST_STROKE_COLOR = "#FBCC38";
  ///// line resize fields
  public static final int LINE_HIEGHT_STOP = 45;
  public static final int LINE_HIEGHT_START_PRE = 0;
  public static final int LINE_HIEGHT_START_POST = 23;
  public static final int SHADOW_CIRCLE_PRE_RADIUS = 15;

  //circle paint fields
  Paint strokeCircle;
  Paint fillCircle;
  Paint shadowCircle;
  Paint line;
  Paint dot;

  //center
  float centerX;
  float centerY;

  //main circle fields
  private int radiusMain = MAIN_CIRCLE_PRE_RADIUS;
  private String colorMain = MAIN_CIRCLE_PRE_STROKE_COLOR;

  //line fields
  private float lineStartY;
  private float lineStopY;
  //shadow circle fields
  private int shadowRadius = SHADOW_CIRCLE_PRE_RADIUS;

  public CancvasCircle(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
  }

  public CancvasCircle(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
  }

  public CancvasCircle(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
  }

  public void init() {

    strokeCircle = new Paint();
    strokeCircle.setAntiAlias(true);
    strokeCircle.setAntiAlias(true);
    strokeCircle.setStrokeWidth(10);
    strokeCircle.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    fillCircle = new Paint();
    fillCircle.setAntiAlias(true);
    fillCircle.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BEC6CC"));
    fillCircle.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    shadowCircle = new Paint();
    shadowCircle.setAntiAlias(true);
    shadowCircle.setColor(Color.parseColor("#1f000000"));
    shadowCircle.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    line = new Paint();
    line.setAntiAlias(true);
    line.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    line.setStrokeWidth(4);
    line.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    dot = new Paint();
    dot.setAntiAlias(true);
    dot.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    dot.setStrokeWidth(4);
    dot.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
  }

  public void resizeStrokeCircleParams(Boolean resize) {
    if (resize) {
      this.radiusMain = MAIN_CIRCLE_POST_RADIUS;
      this.colorMain = MAIN_CIRCLE_POST_STROKE_COLOR;
      this.lineStartY = centerY - LINE_HIEGHT_START_POST;
      this.lineStopY = LINE_HIEGHT_STOP + LINE_HIEGHT_START_POST - 10;
      this.shadowRadius =  LINE_HIEGHT_START_POST;

    } else {
      this.radiusMain = MAIN_CIRCLE_PRE_RADIUS;
      this.colorMain = MAIN_CIRCLE_PRE_STROKE_COLOR;
      this.lineStartY = centerY - LINE_HIEGHT_START_PRE;
      this.lineStopY = LINE_HIEGHT_STOP;
      this.shadowRadius = SHADOW_CIRCLE_PRE_RADIUS;
    }
    invalidate();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    centerX = getWidth() / 2f;
    centerY = getHeight() / 2f;
    int radius = radiusMain;
    float lineStopY = this.lineStopY;
    float lineStartY = this.lineStartY;
    int shadowRadius = this.shadowRadius;

    strokeCircle.setColor(Color.parseColor(colorMain));


    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY - lineStopY - radius, radius, strokeCircle);
    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY - lineStopY - radius, radius, fillCircle);
    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, shadowRadius, shadowCircle);
    canvas.drawLine(centerX, lineStartY, centerX, centerY - lineStopY, line);
    canvas.drawPoint(centerX,centerY,dot);
  }
}
```

is it possible to flip two images like coin in it????

Comment: Yes it is possible.  See https://softwyer.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/1009/

Comment: there is no one to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this method to create a bitmap from XML layout and set it in my codes...

```
  public Bitmap getMarkerBitmapFromView(@DrawableRes int resIdMain, @DrawableRes int resId) {

    View customMarkerView = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_marker, null);
    customMarkerView.findViewById(R.id.custom_marker_firstlayout);
    if(resIdMain != 0){

      customMarkerView.setBackgroundResource(resIdMain);
    }
    ImageView markerImageView = (ImageView) customMarkerView.findViewById(R.id.custom_marker_secondLayout);
    if(resId != 0){
      markerImageView.setImageResource(resId);
    }
    customMarkerView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    customMarkerView.layout(0, 0, customMarkerView.getMeasuredWidth(), customMarkerView.getMeasuredHeight());
    customMarkerView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(customMarkerView.getMeasuredWidth(), customMarkerView.getMeasuredHeight(),
      Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    Drawable drawable = customMarkerView.getBackground();
    if (drawable != null)
      drawable.draw(canvas);
    customMarkerView.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
  }
```

and set it in my canvas view in onDraw() and set it in the middle of my circle:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(getMarkerBitmapFromView(0,guildMarkerICON),convertDpToPixel(76,context),imageHieght,null);
```

because of drawing wrong in different devices i used this methods to change pixel and dp:

```
  public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px,Context context){
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return dp;
  }

  public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp,Context context){
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi/160f);
    return px;
  }
```

and XML layout that provide my bit map (that you can use image or any things you want in it) is (custom_marker.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/custom_marker_firstlayout"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/center_marker_background">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/custom_marker_secondLayout"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

and use this method when you want to change the marker(like moving the map):

```
map.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCameraMoveStarted(int i) {
    canvasView.resizeStrokeCircleParams(true,guildMarkerICON);
  }
});



map.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCameraIdle() {
        canvasView.resizeStrokeCircleParams(false,guildMarkerICON);
      }
    });
```

and finally here i s my custom canvas class that i used  and i passed my custom icon to it by resize method and set it as i want...enjoy it:

```
public class CancvasCircle extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView {
  ///main circle  resize fields
  public static final int MAIN_CIRCLE_PRE_RADIUS = 24;
  public static final int MAIN_CIRCLE_POST_RADIUS = 26;

  public static final String MAIN_CIRCLE_PRE_STROKE_COLOR = "#F44336";

  public static final String MAIN_CIRCLE_POST_STROKE_COLOR = "#FFCC59";
  //FFCC59
  //FBCC38
  ///// line resize fields
  public static final int LINE_HIEGHT_STOP = 24;
  public static final int LINE_HIEGHT_START_PRE = 0;
  public static final int LINE_HIEGHT_START_POST = 11;
  public static final int SHADOW_CIRCLE_PRE_RADIUS = 14;

  private final Context context;

  /// image view fields



  //circle paint fields
  Paint strokeCircle;
  Paint fillCircle;
  Paint shadowCircle;
  Paint line;
  Paint dot;
  Paint  imagePaint;

  //center
  float centerX;
  float centerY;

  //main circle fields
  private int radiusMain = MAIN_CIRCLE_PRE_RADIUS;
  private String colorMain = MAIN_CIRCLE_PRE_STROKE_COLOR;

  //line fieldsاذغ
  private float lineStartY;
  private float lineStopY;
  //shadow circle fields
  private int shadowRadius = SHADOW_CIRCLE_PRE_RADIUS;
  private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
  private int imageTopPadding;
  private int guildMarkerICON
    ;


  public CancvasCircle(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    init();
  }

  public CancvasCircle(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    init();
  }

  public CancvasCircle(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.context = context;
    init();
  }

  public void init() {


    strokeCircle = new Paint();
    strokeCircle.setAntiAlias(true);
    strokeCircle.setAntiAlias(true);
    strokeCircle.setStrokeWidth(12);
    strokeCircle.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    fillCircle = new Paint();
    fillCircle.setAntiAlias(true);
    fillCircle.setColor(Color.parseColor("#af283232"));
    fillCircle.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    shadowCircle = new Paint();
    shadowCircle.setAntiAlias(true);
    shadowCircle.setColor(Color.parseColor("#1f000000"));
    shadowCircle.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    line = new Paint();
    line.setAntiAlias(true);
    line.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    line.setStrokeWidth(4);
    line.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    dot = new Paint();
    dot.setAntiAlias(true);
    dot.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    dot.setStrokeWidth(4);
    dot.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);


  }

  public void resizeStrokeCircleParams(Boolean resize , int guildMarkerICON) {
    this.guildMarkerICON  = guildMarkerICON;
    if (resize) {
      this.radiusMain = (int) convertDpToPixel(MAIN_CIRCLE_POST_RADIUS,context);
      this.colorMain = MAIN_CIRCLE_POST_STROKE_COLOR;
      this.lineStartY = centerY -convertDpToPixel( LINE_HIEGHT_START_POST,context);
      this.lineStopY =convertDpToPixel( LINE_HIEGHT_STOP,context) + convertDpToPixel(LINE_HIEGHT_START_POST,context) -8;
      this.shadowRadius = (int) convertDpToPixel(LINE_HIEGHT_START_POST,context);
      this.imageTopPadding = (int) convertDpToPixel(19,context);

    } else {
      this.radiusMain = (int) convertDpToPixel( MAIN_CIRCLE_PRE_RADIUS,context);
      this.colorMain = MAIN_CIRCLE_PRE_STROKE_COLOR;
      this.lineStartY = centerY - convertDpToPixel(LINE_HIEGHT_START_PRE,context);
      this.lineStopY = convertDpToPixel(LINE_HIEGHT_STOP,context);
      this.shadowRadius = (int) convertDpToPixel(SHADOW_CIRCLE_PRE_RADIUS,context);
      this.imageTopPadding = (int) convertDpToPixel( 28,context);


    }

  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);


    centerX = getWidth() / 2f;
    centerY = getHeight() / 2f;
    int radius = radiusMain;
    float lineStopY = this.lineStopY;
    float lineStartY = this.lineStartY;
    int shadowRadius = this.shadowRadius;
    int imageHieght = this.imageTopPadding;

    strokeCircle.setColor(Color.parseColor(colorMain));



    // if map is moving  (imageHieght == 41)
    // if map is not moving (imageHieght == 56)


    canvas.drawLine(centerX, lineStartY, centerX, centerY - lineStopY, line);
    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY - lineStopY - radius, radius, strokeCircle);
    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY - lineStopY - radius, radius, fillCircle);
    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, shadowRadius, shadowCircle);
    canvas.drawPoint(centerX,centerY,dot);

    canvas.drawBitmap(getMarkerBitmapFromView(0,guildMarkerICON),convertDpToPixel(76,context),imageHieght,null);
invalidate();
  }







  public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px,Context context){

    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return dp;

  }







  public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp,Context context){

    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi/160f);
    return px;

  }




  public Bitmap getMarkerBitmapFromView(@DrawableRes int resIdMain, @DrawableRes int resId) {

    View customMarkerView = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_marker, null);
    customMarkerView.findViewById(R.id.custom_marker_firstlayout);
    if(resIdMain != 0){

      customMarkerView.setBackgroundResource(resIdMain);
    }
    ImageView markerImageView = (ImageView) customMarkerView.findViewById(R.id.custom_marker_secondLayout);
    if(resId != 0){
      markerImageView.setImageResource(resId);
    }
    customMarkerView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    customMarkerView.layout(0, 0, customMarkerView.getMeasuredWidth(), customMarkerView.getMeasuredHeight());
    customMarkerView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(customMarkerView.getMeasuredWidth(), customMarkerView.getMeasuredHeight(),
      Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    Drawable drawable = customMarkerView.getBackground();
    if (drawable != null)
      drawable.draw(canvas);
    customMarkerView.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
  }

}
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See example as custom View.

[image: Preview]

```
public class ViewCircle extends View{
    final Bitmap bms; //source
    final Bitmap bmm; //mask
    final Paint paint;

    public ViewCircle( Context context ){
        super( context );
        bms = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.pr_0000 );
        bmm = Bitmap.createBitmap( bms.getWidth(), bms.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas( bmm );
        paint = new Paint( Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG );
        canvas.drawCircle( bmm.getWidth()/2, bmm.getHeight()/2, Math.min(bmm.getWidth()/2,bmm.getHeight()/2), paint );
        paint.setXfermode( new PorterDuffXfermode( PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN ) );
        canvas.drawBitmap( bms, 0, 0, paint );
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas ){
        super.onDraw( canvas );
        canvas.drawBitmap( bms, 0,0, null );
        canvas.drawBitmap( bmm, bms.getWidth(),0, null );
    }
}
```

Comment: It is screen shot from the custom view. This is working. Sorry.